# Python script is not running in Task Scheduler

Tags: python, command-line, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler, windows-11

So I'm trying to run a Python script that automatically collects Microsoft rewards points, that's specifically in the main.py from this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/charlesbel/Microsoft-Rewards-Farmer) in Task Scheduler.

In Task Scheduler I have it set to "*Run whether user is logged in or not*". with "*Run with highest privileges*" checked.

The trigger is "*Daily*" and I have it to "*8/27/2023 at 8:00 AM*".

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pc7p.png)

In the Actions tab I have one Action - "*Start a program*" that's set to "*C:\Python311\python.exe*" (without quotes) with "*Add arguments (optional)*" set to "*"C:\Users\Kid\Downloads\Microsoft-Rewards-Farmer-master\Microsoft-Rewards-Farmer-master\main.py*" and "*Start in (optional)*" set to "*C:\Users\Kid\Downloads\Microsoft-Rewards-Farmer-master\Microsoft-Rewards-Farmer-master*".

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3Qre.png)

In the settings tab I have "*Allow task to run on demand*" checked, "*Stop the task if it runs longer than: 8 hours*" checked, and "*If the running task does not end when requested, force it to stop*" checked.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfYdQ.png)

in the History tab I see (in order from top to down):

> Task Scheduler launched "{4d6aad46-5acf-4b7a-9f98-f6a5a501ceb7}"  instance of task "\MyTasks\rewards"  for user "Kid" .

> Task Scheduler successfully completed task "\MyTasks\rewards" , instance "{4d6aad46-5acf-4b7a-9f98-f6a5a501ceb7}" , action "C:\Python311\python.exe" with return code 2147942401.

> Task Scheduler successfully finished "{4d6aad46-5acf-4b7a-9f98-f6a5a501ceb7}" instance of the "\MyTasks\rewards" task for user "DESKTOP-U67UPAV\Kid".

All off those events happened within the same minute which means it didn't run correctly

When I have done all of that, I then right clicked the task and pressed run.

It says its running but there's legit nothing in the logs file of the repo.

Any Ideas?

(I have even tried to make a bat file but it didn't work)

`cmd /k "cd C:\Users\Kid\Downloads\Microsoft-Rewards-Farmer-master\Microsoft-Rewards-Farmer-master && main.py"`

Also this is my first Stack overflow post so I apologize if I did something wrong when I asked this question.

Also, I know there are a lot of people reporting the same problem, (which I have tried, and running the task.) I have but it seems like each issue is specific to that person.

Comment: Did you acctualy test run that script manually in CMD or PowerShell: `python C:\Path\To\myscript.py`? You should see runtime errors in console.

Comment: I just did now, and it doesn't work.
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Kid\\logs\\activity.log'`

 I'm not sure why though. Because when I CD into the folder the script is in and do `python main.py` it works. Interesting..

Comment: Nevermind. I just had to run it in administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using PowerShell to run the `python` command and redirect all error or output to a user-created log file. The history tab of the Task Scheduler will not capture runtime errors of actual jobs, just the status of job itself. It appears your code is erring out quickly and so exits quickly which is technically considered a completed job. Before setting up the task, check your very call in a PowerShell terminal by running:

```
C:\Python311\python.exe "C:\Users\Kid\Downloads\Microsoft-Rewards-Farmer-master\Microsoft-Rewards-Farmer-master\main.py"
```

Additionally, the benefit of this PowerShell approach is you can call other commands either `python` or other executables, capture timings, and other useful automation management needs.

Below assumes `python.exe` is recognized in your `Path` environment variable (default in installation), so no need for full path to executable.

**PowerShell** *(save below as a .ps1 script in same folder as python script)*

```
& {
    echo "`nExecution Start: $(Get-Date -format 'u')"

    echo "`nRunning main.py- $(Get-Date -format 'u')"
    python main.py
    
    echo "`nExecution End: $(Get-Date -format 'u')"

} 3>&1 2>&1 > "automation_job_$(Get-Date -format 'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-ss').log"
```

**Windows Task Scheduler**

- Program Script: `PowerShell.exe`
- Add Arguments: `-ExecutionPolicy bypass -File automation_job.ps1`
- Start in: `C:\Users\Kid\Downloads\Microsoft-Rewards-Farmer-master\Microsoft-Rewards-Farmer-master`

Comment: Thank you so much, it turns out I also had to add python to path (I'm not sure how it wasn't on there in the first place).

Also, I don't really need that PowerShell logging script because there's already a activity.log file for the folder. That logs everything.
So can I just leave Arguments blank? And everything would be fine?

Comment: Then just run the task with single command `python` and single argument `main.py`. Hopefully, future readers who need a batch set of commands and own logging can use this PowerShell solution.

Comment: Also how would I make it so it runs PowerShell in administrator mode in the program/script text field?

Comment: Nevermind I forgot to put 'python main.py' in Arguments and just did main.py.